# Find Class name of Super Keyword in JavaParser

Tags: java, super, javaparser

I am developing a Java application based on [JavaParser](https://javaparser.org/). I do not know how to get class name of **Super keyword** used in a method body. As an example, I need to know Super keyword in the below code is referred to class A.

```
class A { 
   public void bar(){...}
}

class B extends A {}

class C extends B {
   void foo(){
      super.bar() // I want to find that the super keyword is referred to Class A.
    }
}
```

I checked these functions (1, 2, and 3) provided by JavaParser, but none of them worked, all return null.

```
MethodCallExpr methodCallExpr = ...
Optional<Expression> scope = methodCallExpr.getScope();
SuperExpr superExp = scope.get().asSuperExpr();
1. superExp.findAll(ClassOrInterfaceDeclaration.class);   and 
2. superExp.getTypeName();
3. superExp.getClassExpr();  //I do not know why this method also returns null
```

Comment: Is `expr` of type `MethodCallExpr`? If so, it appears you have to use `getScope()`: `expr.getScope().asSuperExpr()`

Comment: I actually did the same, but not working. I updated the question to show this.

Comment: super in your example refers to class B (which is the superclass of current class C), not A.

Comment: Assume class C inherits directly from class A. it has no effect, and still results are null.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I find the right method.

```
ResolvedType resolvedType = superExp.calculateResolvedType();
```

This method works correctly if you also add the JavaSymbolSolver to the parser configuration. **JavaSymbolSolver  is necessary to resolve references and find relations between nodes.**

```
TypeSolver reflectionTypeSolver = new ReflectionTypeSolver();
TypeSolver javaParserTypeSolver = new JavaParserTypeSolver(projectSourceDir);
CombinedTypeSolver combinedSolver = new CombinedTypeSolver();
combinedSolver.add(reflectionTypeSolver);
combinedSolver.add(javaParserTypeSolver);
        
ParserConfiguration parserConfiguration = new ParserConfiguration()
                                         .setSymbolResolver(new JavaSymbolSolver(combinedSolver));
        
SourceRoot sourceRoot = new SourceRoot(projectSourceDir.toPath());
sourceRoot.setParserConfiguration(parserConfiguration);
```